# myfaces codi in ear does not intercept @Closeconversationgroup

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss7.x, ear, codi

i have some examples of myfaces codi , but none of them are showing the structure of an ear. also how do I use `@closeConversationGroup` in a ear project, as the interception for the annotations are not getting picked up.

here is how the codes look:

```
<h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="#{userBeanMyFaces.startMe()}" value="Increment String" id="beginid"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{userBeanMyFaces.endConversationGroup()}" value="END Conversation GROUP" id="end1"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{userBeanMyFaces.toDifferentPage()}" value="To a different page" id="differentpage"/>
    </h:form>
```

here is the java code:

```
@Inject
private Conversation conversation;

@Inject
private WindowContext windowContext;

@Produces @Named
private String testString = "string1";

public void startMe() {
    testString = testString + "string2";
}

public String toDifferentPage() {
    return "ok";
}

@CloseConversationGroup(group=ConversationGroup1.class)
public void endConversationGroup() {
    System.out.println("END ACTION HAPENNING");
}
```

here is the page 2 code:

```
<h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{testString}" />
        <h:commandButton action="#{userBeanMyFaces.startMe()}" value="Increment String" id="increment"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{userBeanMyFaces.toDifferentPage()}" value="go to first page" id="changepage"/>
    </h:form>
```

and my closeconversation group does not work with annotation `@CloseConversationGroup(group=ConversationGroup1.class)` does not work at all, i can see there are interceptors in the `myfaces-extcdi-jsf20-module-impl`, but it does not get activated. it activates only if i copy the annocations in my own `bean.xml`. any idea about whats going on?

thanks in advance

thanks

Comment: thanks @Apurv for editing, waiting eagerly for someone to answer, a related post: http://myfaces.10567.n7.nabble.com/CODI-ViewAccessScoped-issue-with-EAR-on-JBoss-7-1-x-td114415.html

Comment: I would move away from EARs at all or just add those libs to WEB-INF/lib. If you check https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI you will find several issues related to EARs. I heard that Apache TomEE handles it better, but I haven't tried it myself.